# Where to log stdout and stderr of a daemon

Tags: linux, daemon

I am writing my first linux daemon and I am wondering where to log its stdout and stderr. It is going to work for all users. I guess I could do it wherever I wanted, I just wonder if there are some good practices I could stick to.

Thank you.

Comment: I belive the answer to your question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180720/maintaining-logging-and-or-stdout-stderr-in-python-daemon

Comment: Hi Nabil. Thanks for that link, it is very interesting. However it doesn't say anything about where is a good place to create those files working as stderr, stdout and stdin (something like /var/log/my_daemon/?)

Comment: *nix daemons, by definition, do not use stdin, stdout or stderr as they do not have a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very definition of a daemon is that it doesn't have anything attached to it's STDOUT and STDERR (and STDIN). Logging should be done through a seperate channel, for example via the syslog facility (see [GNU syslog docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Submitting-Syslog-Messages.html])). Syslog supports several severity levels (debug/informational/warning/critical etc.) which you can use to control the amount of information that gets logged.

Comment: Thanks mtak! and do you know where it is a good folder to create those log files? /var/log/my_daemon/ would be a good choice? Thanks

Comment: According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) it is. If you use syslog, it will automatically determine where to put the log files, and you give the user the option to customize the logging to suit their needs.